# C# Iterating through list of objects

Tags: c#, json.net

First post on here so go easy on me!

I'm trying to deserialize a json document into a list of objects.

So far I've got two classes - one which contains the data structure:

```
 class Server
{
    public string hostname { get; set; }
    public string ipAddress { get; set; }
    public string monitoring { get; set; }
    public int pollingInterval { get; set; }

}
```

The other that contains the collection

```
    class ServerCollection 
{
    public List<Server> servers { get; set; }

}
```

In the applicaion I do a simple ReadAllText and I'm deserializing the object like so

```
private ServerCollection _servers;
string json = File.ReadAllText(@"c:\users\admin\desktop\server.monitoring\servers.json");
_servers = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ServerCollection>(json);
```

I'm struggling to iterate over this using a foreach... Can't think what I'm missing.

```
    Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS1579  foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'ServerCollection' because 'ServerCollection' does not contain a public instance definition for 'GetEnumerator'   Server.Monitoring.Service.Core  C:\Code\Admin\Server.Monitoring\Server.Monitoring.Service.Core\GetSystemHealth.cs   25  Active
```

Any ideas on what I've missed?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What does the code that has the foreach look like and what does the JSON look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class ServerCollection 
{
    public List<Server> servers { get; set; }

}
```

Is not a collection but `Servers` is, you need to iterate over that.

```
foreach (var server in _servers.servers)
{
    //do something with  server
}
```

Comment: Thanks, so simple! Just forgetting that last '.servers'

Comment: @Syngate you should mark this as the right answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your `ServerCollection` class does not implement the `IEnumerable` interface. You have two options:

1. Have `ServerCollection` implement that interface (i.e., `public class ServerCollection : IEnumerable<Server>` and add the necessary methods)
2. Loop over `_servers.servers` instead

The second option is the easier one to get you going, but implementing the interface may have other benefits down the road